# Shortcuts to composing classes, in particular properties and events?

Tags: c#

Are there some kind of shortcuts to composing classes in C# that I'm not seeing. In particular the code to delegate a property or event seems kind of excessive:

```
class MyImpl : ISome {
   ISome _internal;

   public String Name { 
       get { return _internal.Name; }
       set { _internal.Name = value; }
   }

   public event Handler OnCall {
       add { _internal.OnCall += value; }
       remove { _internal.OnCall -= value; }
   }
}
```

I'm hoping for something like:

```
public String Name { _internal.Name; }
public event Handled OnCall { _internal.OnCall; }
```

Or ideally, but I realize this is overly hopeful:

```
delegate _internal.Name;
delegate _intenral.OnCall;
```

I suspect the answer here is "no, there are no shortcuts", but I'd at least like confirmation of that.

Comment: Afraid not, although for the specific case of a getter-only property, if your `Name` property only had a getter then c# 6 would allow you to write it like this: `public string Name => _internal.Name;`

Comment: You can expose complete object `public ISome Internal {get { return _internal; } }` instead of exposing individually some properties of it.